# Is there a way to make iPhone forget the data belonging to one app?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I recently downloaded an app (Rival Knights) which I already had on my iPad, but not on my phone. It gave me the option to write over my saved data and I declined. However now, I've changed my mind and want to start again.

I've tried deleting and re-installing the app, completely resetting my iPhone, deleting the app from my game centre, and making a new apple ID, however none of these have worked.

Is there any other way I can make my phone forget the app so I have a chance of starting again?

Comment: They've probably stored your device token on their servers or iCloud. Check to see if it's in your iCloud storage

Comment: I don't believe it is as I don't have my iCloud enabled, I don't have anything stored in there.

Comment: Many ways to keep track of you. Web site cookies (delete them), your IP address (use Proxy server), file saved in your Library registry (find and delete) ect...

Answer (score 3):

Many apps store data in the iOS Keychain. If the app is deleted the information from the Keychain is NOT deleted from the device. Generally, information such as login info, token, etc. is stored in the Keychain, but nothing prevents the developer from storing other arbitrary data there.

The only way to get around this is to use the Settings to reset the phone data or do a factory reset of the device.

Comment: Great info. I inherited an app that was having issues even after reinstalling, and I couldn't figure out how it was holding on to state between installs.  It seems that even doing a factory reset but restoring everything from backup also restores the keychain.

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the app, all the data from that app gets deleted.

That is how the phone forgets that app.

If the app uses Game Center or another log in to retrieve game state from servers online, then you'll need to temporarily sign out of Game Center and possibly iCloud to remove those files from the phone as well.

I'd start by signing out of Game Center and delete/reinstall the game.

If that doesn't work, you can either check the [specific game / contact that developer](http://support.gameloft.com/?lang=en) and/or sign out of iCloud documents or inspect that data store to see if that game has cloud files.

Once you have a clean start, you will know how to force a change to the cloud to reset the progress to be new.

Comment: Thank you, I tried deleting it and logging out, but unfortunately it didn't work. I've sent an email to the developers now, hopefully they'll get back to me soon. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @hydraulic0 You're welcome. Please share your results here. We encourage people to both ask and answer their questions when they can.

Comment: Absolutley, will do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my iPad. I think I fixed it!

I wanted to reset the game and realised simply reinstalling the game from the App Store didn't mean starting new game. Here's what I did.

1. Delete Rival Knights app.
2. Reinstall the Rival Knight app from App Store
3. Go to **iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage > Backups** (at the top)
4. Tap **This iPad** (or iPad name) **> Backup Options**
5. Tap 'Show All Apps' in Backup Options
6. There is then a list of the apps on your device and the option to switch off the data back up for individual apps. Find Rival Knight app and you can switch off the data back up.
7. A pop up window asks "Do You Want to Turn off Rival Knights Backups and Delete the Data from iCloud?" Choose "Delete."
8. Go back to your home screen and play Rival Knights, you will be playing a brand new game!