# How to reinstall Viber with no connection with my previous Viber usage?

Tags: icloud, applications, backup, privacy, macos

I used to use Viber on iPhone for a while with one set of Viber credentials.

Now I want to reinstall Viber on the same device "erasing its memory" completely: to use it with completely different identity (phone number, name, chat history) -- in a manner that Viber has no way of knowing that it was previously used with a different number on this device / for this Apple ID etc.

iOS 12.x throughout my Viber usage; currently 12.1.2.

**Update (2019-02-07):** Here what I tried so far, with no success:

- `Settings > General > iPhone Storage > Viber > Delete App` (per [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273977/296073))
- `Privacy > Advertising > Limit Ad Tracking`; followed by `> Reset Advertising Identifier`
- `AppleID > iCloud > Viber > Off`
- disabling backups for Viber (per [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245431/296073))
- `AppleID > iCloud > Manage Storage > Backups > (my phone) > Delete Backup`
- rebooting between the above cleanup steps and installing a new copy of Viber
- completely signing out of AppleID, which includes removing all AppleID account-connected data including [Keychain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/334889/296073) and disabling access to any backups
- starting a newly installed Viber when the phone is in Airplane mode (per [3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173772/296073))

Comment: just log out in settings?

Comment: @DaniilManokhin I couldn't find Log Out there. Even after cleaning up Viber data in iCloud backups and iCloud Drive, followed by reinstallation of Viber, it shows my previous number as a default login.

Comment: Surprisingly, no entries containing Viber can be found in Keychain Access on my Mac using the same AppleID as my iPhone.

Comment: try following [this](https://www.imyfone.com/ios-data-erase/erasing-viber-on-iphone/) and seeing if it lets you create a new account

Comment: @DaniilManokhin Following the "How to erase ... manually" section didn't help: my previous phone number is still displayed when I run Viber for a first time after reinstall.

Comment: @DaniilManokhin Updated the question with what I tried so far; all with no success.

Comment: log out then create a new account?

Comment: @DaniilManokhin The point is to make Viber unable to connect my previous and new numbers in any way. When I launch Viber which already shows my previous number at sign in screen, signing in with a new number allows Viber to potentially connect the two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by Deactivating the account. Settings -> Account -> Deactivate account. Then type in your phone number and click deactivate. This will remove all data from the old account and allow you to setup as new.

Comment: If Viber can connect number A to number B, then number B to number C, than it definitely can connect A to C--which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: @wassrubleff edits answer